# Can the product of two orthonormal matrices be an orthonormal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Suppose you have a real orthonormal matrix $L$.

Are there any real orthonormal matrices $X$, other than $L'$ and the identity matrix such that $Y=LX$ is also an orthonormal matrix?

Comment: When you say orthonormal matrix you probably mean [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix); the notion already requires that columns are normalised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of any two orthonormal matrices is also orthonormal. Let
$L,X$ be two such matrices. Then, $(LX)^{*}(LX)=X^{*}L^{*}LX=I$.

To answer your question, yes: pick $X$ to be any (real) orthonormal matrix not equal to $L^*$ or the identity.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what confused me to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

suppse L = $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta& \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$
i.e. a rotation of $\theta$ degrees.  L is ortho-normal.  Now we rotate it $\phi$ more degrees.  And we get a rotation of $\theta + \phi.$  All of those matrices are ortho-normal.